# How to Show text in combobox when no item selected like "..Select room..."

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, combobox

How can I show Text in ComboBox when no item selected in Windows Application using LINQ C# 
Here is my code how I get all rooms.... in Combobox.

```
private void LoadRoom()
        {

            try
            {
                db = new HotelEntities();

                // cmbProvince.Text = "";

                var Room = (from u in db.Room

                            select new { u.RoomId, u.RoomNumber }).ToList();

                cmbRoom.Text = ".. Select.."; // This one do not working.
                cmbRoom.DisplayMember = "RoomNumber";
                cmbRoom.ValueMember = "RoomId";
                cmbRoom.DataSource = Room;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `DataSource` of a combobox, a currencymanager is used on the background and its position is selected (the first item).

Instead of setting DataSource, try adding the items:

```
cmbRoom.Items.AddRange(Room);
```

NB, setting Text as a placeholder will not work if an item is chosen and cleared later, unless you add an extra check (in TextChanged or SelectedIndexChanged)

Answer (score 0):

### Fast solution

Create a source class for your ComboItems, with (at least) the properties to Display and the inner value of the property. If you create a generic class you can use it for all your combo boxes.

```
class ComboDisplay<TSource>
{
     public string Display {get; set;}
     public TSource Value {get; set;}
}

cmbRoom.DisplayMember = nameof(ComboDisplay.Display);
cmbRoom.ValueMember = nameof(ComboDisplay.Value);
```

When you create the data source for your combobox, make sure you add a default value. In the example below I assume that you want to select items of type `Room` in your combo:

```
IEnumerable<Room> availableRooms = myDbContext.Rooms
    .Where(room => room.IsAvailable) 
    .Select(room => new ComboDisplay<Room>
    {
         Display = room.Name,
         Value = new Room
         {
             Id = room.Id,
             ...
         },
    })
    // add a dummy value if nothing is selected
    .Concat(new Room[]
    {
        Display = "Please select a room",
        Value = null, // meaning: nothing selected
    });
```

After selection, use `comboBox1.SelectedValue` to get the selected Room, or null if nothing is selected.

### Create a Special Combobox class

If you have to use this regularly, consider creating a generic sub class of ComboBox that can display items of a certain TSource, and will return null if nothing is selected:

```
class MyComboBox<TSource> : ComboBox
{
    public MyComboBox() : base()
    {
        base.DataSource = this.EmptyList;
        base.DisplayMember = nameof(ComboDisplay.Display);
        base.ValueMember = nameof(ComboDisplay.Value);
    }

    private static readonly EmptyItem = new ComboDisplay
    {
        Display = "Please select a value",
        Value = null,
    }
```

Make a property that returns the available combo items. Make sure that the EmptyItem is always in the collection:

```
public IReadonlyCollection<TSource> ComboItems
{
    get {return (IReadOnlyCollection<TSource>)base.DataSource;}
    set 
    {
        // TODO: check if the empty element is in your list; if not add it
        base.DataSource = value;
    }
}
```

Finally: the function to get the Selected value, or null if nothing is selected:

```
public TSource SelectedValue
{
     get => return (TSource)base.SelectedValue;
     set
     {
         // TODO: check if value is in ComboItems
         base.SelectedValue = value;
     }
}
```

Comment: This is too complicate for me..;) I'am new for this staffs. Is this all code just to have a text when there is no selected item?

Comment: No, it is a general solution, it works for all kinds of items you want in your comboboxes. Whether it is a combobox showing Persons, or whether it is a combobox showing countries. When creating a multi-usable solution, it is more work the first time, but the next time you only have to re-use it, not code again